# Object Deserialization XML Type Cast Error

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-deserialization

I get an error 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'LookUpCodeCollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
when I call the method this line of code below

```
 obj = Deserialize(xml.ToString(), typeof(LookUpCodeCollection));
```

Here is the LookUpCode object

```
    [System.Serializable()]
    public class LookUpCode
    {

        #region "Member Variables"


        private int mCodeID;
        private int? mCategoryID;

        private string mLookUpDescription;
        #endregion

        #region "Properties"
        public int CodeID
        {
            get { return mCodeID; }
            set { mCodeID = value; }
        }

        public int? CategoryID
        {
            get { return mCategoryID; }
            set { mCategoryID = value; }
        }
        public string LookUpDescription
        {
            get { return mLookUpDescription; }
            set { mLookUpDescription = value; }
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

The LookUpCodeCollection

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
[System.Serializable()]
public class LookUpCodeCollection : System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<LookUpCode>, IList<LookUpCode>
{
}
```

The XML

```
- <ArrayOfLookUpCode xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>1</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>1</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>States</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>2</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>2</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>Connecticut Cities by Zipcode</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>3</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>3</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>Zipcode Connecticut Cities</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>4</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>4</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>ContactType</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>5</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>5</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>PhoneType</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>6</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>6</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>DocumentGenerationType</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>7</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>7</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>AmendmentType</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>8</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>8</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>ContractorsTown_TownCodes</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>9</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>9</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>Status</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>10</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>10</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>Upload Document Types</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>11</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>11</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>ExpirationWarning</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>12</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>12</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>RenewalInterval</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>13</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>13</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>Reports</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
- <LookUpCode>
  <CodeID>14</CodeID> 
  <CategoryID>14</CategoryID> 
  <LookUpDescription>ActiveInactive</LookUpDescription> 
  </LookUpCode>
  </ArrayOfLookUpCode>
```

The Call To Deserialize Method

```
        //Declare the variables
        LookUpCodeCollection obj = new LookUpCodeCollection();
```

`obj = Deserialize(xml.ToString(), typeof(LookUpCodeCollection));`

The Deserialize Method

```
        private static object Deserialize(string input, Type toType)
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(toType);

        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
            return ser.Deserialize(sr);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Deserialize()` returns an `object`. It will be of the appropriate type, but since C# is a strongly-typed language (and there is no implicit cast from `object` to `LookUpCodeCollection`), the compiler does not know how to assign the result to a variable of type `LookUpCodeCollection`. As the error is suggesting, you will need to explicitly cast it:

```
LookUpCodeCollection obj = (LookUpCodeCollection)Deserialize(xml.ToString(), typeof(LookUpCodeCollection));
```

Alternatively you can make your `Deserialize` method generic:

```
private static T Deserialize<T>(string input)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
        return (T)ser.Deserialize(sr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the result of the deserialization to `LookUpCodeCollection` again:

```
(LookUpCodeCollection)ser.Deserialize(sr);
```

Although you `obj` object has the correct type, the return type of the `Deserialize` method is `object` so it is not casted to the desired result type. You can change the return type of your deserialization method to `LookUpCodeCollection` and the deserialization should work (without further code changes):

```
private static LookUpCodeCollection Deserialize(string input, Type toType)
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ser = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(toType);

    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(input))
    {
        return (LookUpCodeCollection)ser.Deserialize(sr);
    }
}
```

In order to be more flexible, common methods (in this case `Deserialize`) use often [the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework - Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx), so you need always to cast to the derived type in such cases (in your case the `LookUpCodeCollection`).

If you want to reuse your deserialize function with different data types, than have a look at [C# Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

Comment: I am trying to type cast so I could reuse the Deserialize method for many different object types.

Comment: Then the generic solution of @lc. is more appropriate here.